# any way to fix delphi to always show compiler hints?

Tags: delphi, ide, hints

All of a sudden, my Delphi 10.3 stopped showing compiler hints in some (but not all) procedures of one project (but not others - and may I add that I have far more complex ones). MadDebug stopped working with this error:

> [madExcept Warning] Mapping binary file failed (1)

Enforcing hints with `$` and un/re-installing MadCollection doesn't help.

Comment: Check what is checked in the project options, in Building / Delphi Compiler / Hints and Warnings. Compare between two projects.

Comment: @fpiette they are checked in all projects (and optimization is off). looks like something got bugged and the madexcept warning is the second manifestation of it. tried making a fresh project with the same units, doesn't work. must be something code-related, although i don't think i used anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously (just another one of many) bug(s) in the delphi environment. The problem disappeared when I changed the platform from 32-bit to 64-bit Windows (so I do the development on 64-bit and finalize on 32-bit).